Soft delete and Purge Protection should be enabled and retention days should be 90 days as Terraform error
We are using terraform to deploy azure key vault, getting error to enable Soft delete and Purge Protection should be enabled and retention days should be 90 days, as we have already given the purge protection and retention days in the terraform configuration files, getting below error to enable purge protection and retention days.


Error: creating Key Vault (Subscription: "XXX"
Resource Group Name: "AZR-WHK-Appservice-POC"
Key Vault Name: "kv-sctddi-poc"): performing CreateOrUpdate: vaults.VaultsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=0 -- Original Error: Code="RequestDisallowedByPolicy" Message="Resource 'kv-sctddi-p
oc' was disallowed by policy. Reasons: 'Soft delete and Purge Protection should be enabled and retention days should be 90 days'. See error details for policy resource IDs." Target="kv-sctddi-poc" AdditionalInfo=[{"info
":{"evaluationDetails":{"evaluatedExpressions":[{"expression":"type","expressionKind":"Field","expressionValue":"Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults","operator":"Equals","path":"type","result":"True","targetValue":"Microsoft.KeyV
ault/vaults"},{"expression":"Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/createMode","expressionKind":"Field","expressionValue":"default","operator":"Equals","path":"properties.createMode","result":"False","targetValue":"recover"},{"expr
ession":"Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/softDeleteRetentionInDays","expressionKind":"Field","operator":"NotEquals","path":"properties.softDeleteRetentionInDays","result":"True","targetValue":"90"}],"reason":"Soft delete and
Purge Protection should be enabled and retention days should be 90 days"},"policyAssignmentDisplayName":"VPCx Landing Zone KeyVault","policyAssignmentId":"/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/Production/prov
iders/Microsoft.Authorization/policyAssignments/vpcx-lzn-keyvault","policyAssignmentName":"vpcx-lzn-keyvault","policyAssignmentParameters":{},"policyAssignmentScope":"/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/Pro
duction","policyDefinitionDisplayName":"VPCx - Key vaults should have soft delete and purge protection enabled and retention set as 90 days","policyDefinitionEffect":"Deny","policyDefinitionId":"/providers/Microsoft.Man
agement/managementGroups/Production/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/vpcx-lzn-keyvault-enable-soft-delete-purge-retention-days-90","policyDefinitionName":"vpcx-lzn-keyvault-enable-soft-delete-purge-re
tention-days-90","policyDefinitionReferenceId":"vpcx-lzn-keyvault-enable-soft-delete-purge-retention-days-90","policyExemptionIds":[],"policySetDefinitionDisplayName":"VPCx Landing Zone KeyVault Baseline","policySetDefi
nitionId":"/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/Production/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policySetDefinitions/vpcx-landingzone-keyvault-baseline","policySetDefinitionName":"vpcx-landingzone-keyvault-baseline"},"type":"PolicyViolation"}]
with azurerm_key_vault.azure_key_vault,
on main.tf line 122, in resource "azurerm_key_vault" "azure_key_vault":
122: resource "azurerm_key_vault" "azure_key_vault"

data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}

data "azuread_service_principal" "azure_service_app_principle" {
  client_id = "XXX"
}


resource "tls_private_key" "ssh" {
  algorithm = "RSA"
  rsa_bits  = 4096
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "azure_key_vault" {
  name         = "azure-key-vault-secret"
  value        = "sctddi"
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.azure_key_vault.id
  depends_on   = [azurerm_key_vault.azure_key_vault]
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "ssh-private-key" {
  name         = "ssh-private-key"
  value        = tls_private_key.ssh.private_key_pem
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.azure_key_vault.id
  depends_on   = [azurerm_key_vault.azure_key_vault]


}
resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "ssh-public-key-pem" {
  name         = "ssh-public-key-pem"
  value        = tls_private_key.ssh.public_key_pem
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.azure_key_vault.id
  depends_on   = [azurerm_key_vault.azure_key_vault]


}
resource "azurerm_key_vault_secret" "ssh-public-key-openssh" {
  name         = "ssh-public-key-openssh"
  value        = tls_private_key.ssh.public_key_openssh
  key_vault_id = azurerm_key_vault.azure_key_vault.id
  depends_on   = [azurerm_key_vault.azure_key_vault]


}

resource "azurerm_key_vault" "azure_key_vault" {

  depends_on = [data.azurerm_client_config.current, data.azuread_service_principal.azure_service_app_principle]


  enable_rbac_authorization     = true
  purge_protection_enabled      = true
  soft_delete_retention_days    = 90
  enabled_for_disk_encryption   = true
  sku_name                      = "standard"
  public_network_access_enabled = false
  name                          = "kv-sctddi-poc"
  location                      = var.location
  resource_group_name           = var.resourcegroupname
  tenant_id                     = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id


  network_acls {
    default_action = "Deny"
    bypass         = "AzureServices"
  }


  access_policy {

    tenant_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
    object_id = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id

    key_permissions = [
      "Get", "List", "Update", "Create", "Import", "Delete", "Recover", "Backup", "Restore", "Decrypt",
      "Encrypt", "UnwrapKey", "WrapKey", "Verify",
      "Sign", "Purge", "Release", "Rotate", "GetRotationPolicy", "SetRotationPolicy"
    ]
    secret_permissions = ["Get", "List", "Set", "Delete", "Recover", "Backup", "Restore", "Purge"]

    storage_permissions = [
      "Get", "Backup", "Delete", "DeleteSAS", "Get", "GetSAS", "List", "ListSAS", "Purge",
      "Recover", "RegenerateKey", "Restore", "Set", "SetSAS", "Update"
    ]


  }

}


{
  "properties": {
    "displayName": "VPCx - Key vaults should have soft delete and purge protection enabled and retention set as 90 days",
    "policyType": "Custom",
    "mode": "All",
    "description": "Accidental deletion of a key vault can lead to permanent data loss. Soft delete allows you to recover an accidently deleted key vault for a retention period configured to a provided number of days. Purge protection protects you from insider attacks by enforcing a mandatory retention period for soft deleted key vaults. No one inside your organization or Microsoft will be able to purge your key vaults during the soft delete retention period.     ",
    "metadata": {
      "category": "Key Vault",
      "createdBy": "",
      "createdOn": "2024-04-05T12:25:59.6392467Z",
      "updatedBy": null,
      "updatedOn": null
    },
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "parameters": {
      "effect": {
        "type": "String",
        "metadata": {
          "displayName": "Effect",
          "description": "The effect determines what happens when the policy rule is evaluated to match"
        },
        "allowedValues": [
          "Audit",
          "Deny",
          "Disabled"
        ],
        "defaultValue": "Deny"
      }
    },
    "policyRule": {
      "if": {
        "allOf": [
          {
            "field": "type",
            "equals": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults"
          },
          {
            "not": {
              "field": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/createMode",
              "equals": "recover"
            }
          },
          {
            "anyOf": [
              {
                "field": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/enableSoftDelete",
                "exists": "false"
              },
              {
                "field": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/enablePurgeProtection",
                "exists": "false"
              },
              {
                "field": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/enableSoftDelete",
                "equals": "false"
              },
              {
                "field": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/enablePurgeProtection",
                "equals": "false"
              },
              {
                "field": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/softDeleteRetentionInDays",
                "notEquals": "90"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      "then": {
        "effect": "[parameters('effect')]"
      }
    },
    "versions": [
      "1.0.0"
    ]
  },
  "id": "/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementGroups/Production/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/vpcx-lzn-keyvault-enable-soft-delete-purge-retention-days-90",
  "type": "Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions",
  "name": "vpcx-lzn-keyvault-enable-soft-delete-purge-retention-days-90",
  "systemData": {
    "createdBy": "daab",
    "createdByType": "Application",
    "createdAt": "2024-04-05T12:25:59.6005721Z",
    "lastModifiedBy": "aab",
    "lastModifiedByType": "Application",
    "lastModifiedAt": "2024-04-05T12:25:59.6005721Z"
  }
}



The error message indicates that the Azure Policy assigned to your subscription is disallowing the creation of the Key Vault because Soft delete and Purge Protection should be enabled, and the retention days should be set to 90 days. Kindly check your policy configuration for the Key Vault to ensure that purge_protection_enabled is set to true and soft_delete_retention_days is set to 90 days.

The Policy will deny the resource if the values do not match the specified values. You can check your policy to ensure the values are specified correctly, as shown here

I was able to create azure key vault using the az cli command
az keyvault create --location EastUS --name=kv-sctddi-poc --resource-group AZR-WHK-Appservice-POC --sku standard --enable-rbac-authorization --bypass AzureServices --default-action Deny --retention-days 90 --enable-purge-protection

Are there any exceptions for that resource group, the one you created using Azure CLI? If possible, share your Azure Policy code snapshot here. If the policy is implemented at the subscription level, you won't be able to create the resource from anywhere unless you have excluded any resource group in the policy

There are no exceptions for that resource group as I was able to create azure key vault using azure cli commands

Hi @Nick , When I try to create a Key Vault from the portal or CLI with Purge Protection disabled and Soft Delete retention days set to 70, the policy is blocking the creation.

I was also able to create it from CLI initially, but once the policy was assigned, it got blocked. If you are still able to create it from CLI, you should check the policy assignment and the scope of the policy.

Hello Venkat,
I have added the policy definition in the above reference details for your reference

Hi Nick, after many trials, I concluded that the policy expects Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/enableSoftDelete to be enabled. However, Terraform does not have argument to enable soft delete, while the CLI and Portal accept it.

I have to edit some policy in my organization, which is taking lot of approvals will test it after the policy changes done, but there must be update in terraform to keep softdelete as true

The policy expects the Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/enableSoftDelete to be enabled. However, Terraform does not have an argument to enable soft delete in its code, while the CLI and Portal accept it.
By default, Terraform supports enabling purge protection and soft delete options during Key Vault creation.
  purge_protection_enabled      = true
  soft_delete_retention_days    = 90

To resolve the issue, you may remove the below part from your policy or run CLI commands within Terraform.
{  
"field":  "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/enableSoftDelete",  "exists":  "false"  
},

Azure Policy
{
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults"
        },
        {
          "anyOf": [
            {
              "field": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/enablePurgeProtection",
              "exists": "false"
            },
            {
              "field": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/softDeleteRetentionInDays",
              "notEquals": "90"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "[parameters('effect')]"
    }
  },
  "parameters": {
    "effect": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "Effect",
        "description": "The effect determines what happens when the policy rule is evaluated to match"
      },
      "allowedValues": [
        "Audit",
        "Deny",
        "Disabled"
      ],
      "defaultValue": "Deny"
    }
  }
}

While creating the Key vault from portal policy is blocking resource creation if retention days are set to 75 days with purge protection enabled

While creating the Key vault from portal policy is blocking resource creation if retention days are set to 75 days with purge protection enabled

Azure CLI command is blocking resource creation if retention days are set to 75 with purge protection enabled

Azure CLI command is blocking resource creation if retention days are set to 90 with purge protection disabled

The policy is accepted the Key vault creation with Purge protection enabled and soft deleted days 90 days from both CLI and Portal.

Terraform with Azure CLI
    provider "azurerm" {
      features {}
    }
    
    resource "null_resource" "powershell" {
      provisioner "local-exec" {
        command = <<-EOT
        az keyvault create --location EastUS --name kv-sytedctddi-poc1dr --resource-group Venkat --sku standard --enable-rbac-authorization --bypass AzureServices --default-action Deny --retention-days 90 --enable-purge-protection
        EOT
      }
    }

Terraform apply

Portal View

